# Can you take 10 on spellcraft checks to copy a spell into a spellbook?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, wizard

*"At the end of the hour, he must make a Spellcraft check (DC 15 + spell’s level). A wizard who has specialized in a school of spells gains a +2 bonus on the Spellcraft check if the new spell is from his specialty school. If the check succeeds, the wizard understands the spell and can copy it into his spellbook (see Writing a New Spell into a Spellbook)."*

*"When your character is not in immediate danger or distracted, you may choose to take 10. Instead of rolling 1d20 for the skill check, calculate your result as if you had rolled a 10. For many routine tasks, taking 10 makes them automatically successful. Distractions or threats (such as combat) make it impossible for a character to take 10."*

**Can you take 10 on spellcraft checks to copy a spell into a spellbook?**

Comment: Related, see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97857/can-a-character-take-10-or-20-on-a-spellcraft-check-to-identify-magical-items/123310#123310) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97857/can-a-character-take-10-or-20-on-a-spellcraft-check-to-identify-magical-items)

Comment: For further comparison, [the FAQ says](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qby) that a magic item creator *can* take 10 on the Spellcraft skill check that's made to create a magic item.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes

Copying a spell from a spellbook isn't immediate danger or a distraction from itself, so there's no inherent reason this wouldn't work. Of course, if you're trying to copy a spell in situations where there are distractions or danger then you would need to roll as normal.

This is distinct from the the answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97857/can-a-character-take-10-or-20-on-a-spellcraft-check-to-identify-magical-items) about distractions when identifying magic, as copying a spell doesn't require concentration to sustain a spell like *detect magic*.